# Is multi-threading the answer? Handling lots of processing

Tags: .net, multithreading, process, load-balancing

We currently have a method that reads customer data from our database, checks the data for some conditions, then sends out email notifications based on if those conditions are met.

This process is run every minute

However, as more customers are added to our system, that same process will need to repeat for each customer.

Of course, it wouldn't make sense to do a FOR loop through each customer like so:

```
CUSTOMERS = get_all_customers()
FOREACH( customer in CUSTOMERS )
    MyMethod(customer)
END FOR
```

The above seems very inefficient.

I am thinking a multi-threaded approach will work better, like so:

```
CUSTOMERS = get_all_customers()
FOREACH( customer in CUSTOMERS )
    StartNewThread( MyMethod(customer) )
END FOR
```

Are there any issues with that? Particularly, let's say there are 10 customers then I'm sure it will be fine -- 10 threads will span. But what happens when there are 50 or 100 customers? This means every minute 100 threads will spawn! What are my alternatives?

Comment: Async. Rather than spawn off a bunch of threads which will probably sit around doing nothing being blocked, just have a few threads that aren't blocked waiting for I/O and stuff.

Comment: since the .NET tag is there... I assume you can use Tasks or directly utilize the Thread Pool and let that handle a lot of the work for you on thread efficiency. Otherwise if you always create more threads than you have processors, then you're really not gaining any performance anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take overhead time/context switch into account, that way if you have 1000 users, would be 1000 threads, plus thread creation time. I suggest you this:

```
CUSTOMERS = get_all_customers()
size = CUSTOMERS.size()/1000;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    StartNewThread(MyMethodOnArray(Array, size*i, size*(i+1) -1));
}
```

Get a thread for every 1k register, compensating the overhead. Or do this, use a ThreadPool, static number of available threads, and have each thread to take a client register, and use a synchronised function which returns the current index in the array and increases it by one.
In Java something like

```
int current_client;
synchronized int getIndex() {
    int j = current_client;
    current_client++;
    if (j < CUSTOMERS.size())
         return j;
     return -1;
}
```

Check for -1, if a thread gets that, it stops.

Comment: Thanks. So for the first method, are you suggesting to sequentially handle 1000 customers per thread? So ``FOR X=1 to 1000 { myMethod() }`` is what will exist in the thread? Would that cause any CPU hog? Or is it worse off having 1 thread per method?

Comment: It was an example, overhead depends in the number of threads created, remember that there are system threads, and user threads, and user threads are mapped to system threads, and each of your thread is given certain time. The more threads there are, the less time each thread has, and the total overhead time would be, numberofthreads*overheadtime, which could become greater than the actual time of processing.  I would go with the Thread Pool solution, because each operation of "mail sending" can take different amount of time, depending on network congestion and stuff.